# How to interpret the characteristic roots of moment equation of a AR(2) model?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive

I am learning the financial time series using the book 'Analysis of financial time series' by Ruey Tsay. In chapter 2, they introduced AR(2) models.

The moment equation (which is the function between the autocorrelations), is a second-order polynomials. And by solving the equation, if there is a real solution with two roots, he said the AR(2) model can be regarded as an AR(1) model operates on top of another AR(1) model.And the ACF of r is then a mixture of two exponential decays.

I kind of get the idea, because you can write the moment equation in this way: 
(1-w1B)(1-w2B)=0

Compare to AR(1), its 1-w1B = 0, (B is the back-shift operator, or you can use L, the lag operator, the same thing), and AR(1) model, ACF is an exponential decay. So for AR(2), this looks like two exponential decays. But my question is, I didn't learn mixture of exponentials before, how do I know the relation between the lag-3 autocorrelation and lag-2, or lag-1 from the roots w1, and w2? Or put it this way, what is the parameters for the mixtured exponentials from w1, w2 I calculated?